# Keeping Session ID in Objective-C App

Tags: objective-c, ios, rest, singleton, global-variables

I'm developing an app the accesses a web server by REST. I want to keep the session ID for any View Controller or Class can access it. What is the correct (or the best) way to do it? Singletons, global variables or neither?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the session only has 1 field and you want to save it in case the app is closed, NSUserDefaults is the simplest way.

If you don't want to save the session or if it's complex, you should use singleton.

Answer (score 1):

I think using NSUserDefaults is the way to go here.